# Powershell Script Receiving Errors when Removing All Document Files on Network Share

Tags: powershell, permissions, network-drive

I've been receiving errors when running the script. It will access the drive and write the filenames to my log as specified, but will not remove the files on the share drive due to a permissions error. I'm logged in as the Administrator and have re-wrote permissions to the whole drive, but still do not have access.

Here is the code:

```
$servers = Get-content "D:\Scripts\servers.txt"
$logpath = "d$\Documents"
$logFile = "D:\Scripts\log.txt"
$Date = Get-Date
$error.clear()

foreach($server in $servers){

$fail =" $Date - Failed.  $server did not respond to a ping command.  No files have been deletedfrom $server."
$notpresent = "$Date - Failed.  The specified log folder doesn't seem to be present on $server."
$nologs = "There are no log files to be deleted on $server."

$UNCpath = "\\" +$server+ "\" +$logpath
#Ping server to validate the server is online and accessible
If ($server|?{ (gwmi Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address='$_'").StatusCode -eq 0 }){

    # The server IS pingable, but the folder does not exist.
    If (!(Test-Path $UNCpath)){Write-output $notpresent `r`n | Out-File $logFile -append}

    # The server IS pingable, and the folder does exist
    else{
        $files = (dir -r $UNCpath -include *.doc,*.pdf,*.docx,*.xls,*.xlsx | where {$_.lastwritetime -le (get-date).adddays(-90) -and !$_.psiscontainer})
        foreach ($file in $files){
            If ($file -eq $null){write-output $nologs `r`n | Out-File $logFile -append}
            Else{
                write-output $file.name | Out-File $logFile -append
                remove-item $file
            }
        }
    }
}

# The server is NOT pingable.
else{Write-output $fail `r`n | Out-File $logFile -append}

If ($error.count -ne "0"){write-output $error | Out-File $logfile -append}
Else{write-output "The log file removal script has completed successfully." | Out-File $logfile -append}'
```

Comment: Could you give us more info about how you are running this script?  Are you running it remotely?  Scheduled task?  With a service?

Comment: I am running the script from another remote machine and directly the script to run on the server in which the files are located I want to remove. It is currently not scheduled, but once I get this permissions issued solved, it will be.

Comment: Are you running on Machine A to access the files on Machine B, or using Machine A to execute the script remotely on Machine B to access the files on Machine C?

Comment: Running script on machine A to access files on machine B. I figured out the solution -- I simply added -force after remove-item $file. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

OP posted his own answer as a comment. I'm putting it here as a "real" answer. Bold/italic emphasis by me.

> Running script on machine A to access files on machine B. I figured
>   out the solution -- **I simply added -force after remove-item $file.**
>   Worked like a charm. *– gp80586 Aug 10 at 20:48*

Please do not vote on this answer, it's not from me.

Comment: I upvoted this because I skimmed over gp's comment. Thankyou for putting the answer where is belongs. I was reading over UAC permissions and RunAsAdministrator stuff for 30 min before I found *this* correct answer thanks you you galaktor.

Comment: I've been there :-) I found this post was for the precise same reason. Glad it helped!